# How to enter a folder with name # from the command line in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line

I have a folder, name of my folder is  **#**. How can I change directory (cd) to this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to escape the `#` with a `\`

For example I created a folder called `#test` in my home folder

```
warren@VBox:~$ ls
a.out  bad.c.save  Desktop    Music     share      #test
bad    bad.s       Documents  Pictures  src        Videos
bad.c  crap        Downloads  Public    Templates
```

As expected `cd #test` does not work because everything after the `#` is a comment

```
warren@VBox:~$ cd #test
warren@VBox:~$ ls
a.out  bad.c.save  Desktop    Music     share      #test
bad    bad.s       Documents  Pictures  src        Videos
bad.c  crap        Downloads  Public    Templates
```

But `cd \#test` does

```
warren@VBox:~$ cd \#test
warren@VBox:~/#test$ ls
hjjhk.txt  #test1
warren@VBox:~/#test$
```